# SQL select statement with blank in passing parameter

Tags: php, sql, t-sql

I'm trying to write a search function and am using multiple drop-down lists for search criteria.

i have a sql statement like

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE OFFICE='$office', NAME='$name', DEPARTMENT='$department';
```

Sometime I want to search with specific 'name' but without talking about 'department' and 'office'. But when I pass Blank '' to '$office' and '$department' it only return the person with no office and department. Is there anyway around to overcome it?

I tried to use '%' instead of blank but it didn't work as well.
I'm coding with php and MSSQL.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could any one about this sql? I think it should be `WHERE OFFICE = `$office` AND NAME='$name'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to work with wildcards, you dont need `=`, but `LIKE`. Unsure if this query works, but try it:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE OFFICE LIKE '$office', NAME LIKE '$name', DEPARTMENT LIKE '$department';
```

Now you just have to check if the field is blank, if yes, replace it with a `%`. As i said, im unsure. I dont have a database availible at the moment for testing this.

Answer (score 0):

for achieving this you have to write some php code like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE";
if(isset($office)){
    $sql .= "OFFICE='$office',";
}
if(isset($name)){
    $sql .= " NAME='$name',";
}

if(isset($department)){
    $sql .= " DEPARTMENT='$department'";
}
```

Comment: Nope you dont have to. MySQL is extremely powerful on its own. It just gets pretty cryptical if you try to archive something complex so most people avoid writing long queries. But its powerful as hell.

Answer (score 0):

**You can easily do this as follow:**

```
if(isset($office) && isset($department)){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE OFFICE='$office', NAME='$name', DEPARTMENT='$department'";
}
else{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NAME LIKE '$name'";
}

mysql_query($connection, $sql);
```

Comment: String delimiter behind the 2nd `$sql` is missing.